# Get value from webhook in groovy script jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, bitbucket, webhooks

I am using the generic webhook trigger plugin to trigger jenkins jobs based on the webhook from bitbucket

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin

I am able to extract values from the post payload of the webhook.  I use them to choose the branch to be built.

I would like to have access to those same variables in my groovy scripts that I run using the groovy plugin but so far I can't figure out how to get them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- First check that "Use groovy Sandbox is UNCHECKED"
- Then try ***println env***
- or you may define a variable and then print it

  - def repoName = env.gitlabSourceRepoName
  - println "Repository Name: " + repoName